# Is this proof for the "Poisson Summation Formula" correct?

Tags: summation, fourier-series, fourier-transform

So I was snooping around Proof Wiki for the *Poisson Summation Formula* proof and came across this:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Poisson_Summation_Formula

In the end it makes the statement:

> Therefore by the definition of the Fourier series of $\space f \space$ :
>
> $F(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(x)e^{ikx}$

Is it not $\space \hat{f}(x)e^{ik2\pi x}$?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are right, this is a typo (and since we need the equality only for $x= 0$ it doesn't change the argument)

Comment: @user1952009 - Than you so much. I had a feeling, I was literally sat here for 30 minutes looking at it.